# "nomodeset" not working on ASUS FX553VE Laptop

Tags: asus

I've installed Ubuntu via USB stick and it all worked fine. I got it all set up until the Point where Ubuntu asks to reboot the Computer to finish the Installation. When I clicked on "ok" the entire Computer froze and Nothing happened for 5 minutes. Thats when I decided to cut the power.

Now there are two cases, with and without "nomodeset":

With "nomodeset":

Just to be clear, when Pressing "e" on the boot screen with "Ubuntu" selected I added "nomodeset" to the following line:

```
linux     /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-10-generic root=UUID= ..... ro  quiet splash nomodeset $vt_handoff
```

Then I press F10 to boot and the following happens:

- Screen switches Purple and black a few times
- The Standard bootup Animation Shows and then after the following screen Nothing happens anymore:
  [Picture of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OodOm.jpg)

Without "nomodeset":

Linux just gets stuck in the normal boot up screen but the Little dots that normally fill up with time aren't visible. It stays that way for at least 5 minutes until I cut the power.

My Computer:

- Asus FX553VE Laptop
- Intel Core i7-7700HQ
- NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1050TI
- 16GB RAM

Maybe it is important that before Ubuntu I tried installing Arch Linux*. There I sooner or later got the message that was something About CPU stalling.

*I sometimes get in over my head.